# Why does accessing /localhost give "File not found" error?

Tags: apache2, lamp

I was trying to install a LAMP stack following the [howtounix.info](http://howtounix.info/howto/LAMP-on-Ubuntu-with-tasksel-tool) tutorial.

I could install it but when I try to access localhost using `/localhost` on Firefox it gave me an error, it appears "File not found" like I didn't have lamp server installed.

Comment: it's `http://localhost` not `/localhost`

Comment: @Achu: please consider creating an answer so that this question can be marked as solved and you can get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address is not correct.

It should be `http://localhost`, not `/localhost` only.