# Localhost: Updating files to localhost

Tags: files, apache2, lamp

I have [set up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329049/) a LAMP stack that listens on localhost and serves files from a directory.

I save a html file into my localhost directory, then I try to change it (and I save it again into my localhost directory). However, when I access the file via localhost it shows me the old file without the changes. If I access the file via my home folder it appearers as the current file (with last changes).

Do you know how can I solve this problem? Thanks, berga007

Comment: Maybe related to caching in your browser? If you use Chrome open up the **Developer Tools** (F12) and **Disable Cache** and try again.

Comment: I'm actually using Mozila firefox (the default browser) it works the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a caching problem to me, depending on the changes you're making. If you're making CSS or JS changes, then, yes, it's probably caching the page. Then, when you go to a different URL, your browser is pulling a "new" page. If you are changing CSS or JS, here's an article from Mozilla about clearing your cache in FF. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache

If you're making other changes (such as changing the wording or layout), it may be something else. Have you tried to edit and save your HTML file directly from the localhost directory? Or do you edit it, save it elsewhere, then copy it back into your localhost directory?

Comment: The problem was all about the cahce. I press CTRL F5 and the changes were apllied correctly.